# AngularJS error: TypeError: v2.login is not a function

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularjs-ng-click, firebase-authentication

I would like to call the login function when I click the login button but keep getting the error message in the title. Can someone point out the error in my script?

login.js code below:

```js
/*global Firebase, angular, console*/

'use strict';
// Create a new app with the AngularFire module
var app = angular.module("runsheetApp");

app.controller("AuthCtrl", function ($scope, $firebaseAuth) {
    var ref = new Firebase("https://xxxxx.firebaseio.com");
    function login() {
        ref.authWithPassword({
            email    : "xxxxx",
            password : "xxxx"
        }, function (error, authData) {
            if (error) {
                console.log("Login Failed!", error);
            } else {
                console.log("Authenticated successfully with payload:", authData);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.21/angular.min.js"></script>
```

And the code for login.html is also below:

```html
<div class="container" style="max-width: 300px">
    <form class="form-signin">       
      <h2 class="form-signin-heading" style="text-align: center">Please Sign In</h2>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" ng-model = "username" placeholder="Email Address" required="" autofocus="" />
        </br>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" ng-model = "password" placeholder="Password" required=""/>
        </br>
      <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" ng-click="login()">Login</button>   
    </form>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In my case, I was having an exact same issue as yours. However, coming across [gkalpak's answer](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/12353#issuecomment-121685357) to such a scenario helped me out.

Turned out to be what I was calling was addBuddy() function, from a form named "addBuddy". The solution was to change the name of either of the two things to make one stand out or differentiable from the other. I changed the name of the form to "addBuddyForm" and voila! My function worked!

Here's a snippet of my case:

```
<form name="addBuddy" class="form-horizontal" novalidate>
...
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-info" ng-click="addBuddy()>Submit</button>
```

Which, I changed to:

```
<form name="addBuddyForm" class="form-horizontal" novalidate>
...
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-info" ng-click="addBuddy()>Submit</button>
```

...and it worked! :)

Comment: In my case, I had a function called 'addBuddy()'.
I also had a boolean that I was setting 'addBuddy = true' / 'addBuddy = false' when I was attempting to display the page where 'addBuddy()' was being shown to the user.


It seems like Angular runs a comparison against variables and functions to make sure there's no overlaps. it compares them as v1.VarFnName (as string) != v2.VarFnName.

`function doComparison(v1, v2) {
      for (var i = 0, ii = predicates.length; i < ii; i++) {
        var result = compare(v1.predicateValues[i], v2.predicateValues[i]);`

Answer (score 67):

Edge case here, but I want to mention it for posterities' sake. I got this same error when using the controllerAs pattern with a form `name` with the same value as `ng-submit`. For example:

`<form name="authCtrl.signUp" ng-submit="authCtrl.signUp()">`

Throws: *TypeError: v2.signUp is not a function*

The solution was to change the name of the form to something different:

`<form name="authCtrl.signUpForm" ng-submit="authCtrl.signUp()">`

Comment: This was absolutely the answer to my issue. It goes to show how it isn't always a case of 'This is all fundamental stuff'. Thanks. I don't need the controller on my element because I am using a directive.

Comment: This was really helpful to me and exactly my issue too, thanks!

Comment: I had a similar issue where I got the error described here when assigning a value to a scope variable inside a directive. Changing the name of the scope variable in the directive resolved the issue. That makes me think a parent scope somewhere above had already assigned a method to that $scope variable.

Comment: Well, I guess this wasn't an edge case after all... ;-)

Comment: Yo! Fixed my bug! Are you the Aaron Gray who was my instructor at Galvanize?

Comment: @ThomasDavidKehoe Glad to hear it! I did live in Denver for a while, but I think its a different Aaron Gray. ;-)

Comment: This was the answer to my issue. Thanks a lot. :)

Answer (score 11):

In AngularJS call the function from view it must be in the $scope.

**JS**

```
// exposes login function in scope
$scope.login = login;
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="AuthCtrl" style="max-width: 300px"> <!-- I notice here for include ng-controller to your main div -->
<form class="form-signin">       
  <h2 class="form-signin-heading" style="text-align: center">Please Sign In</h2>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" ng-model = "username" placeholder="Email Address" required="" autofocus="" />
    </br>
  <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" ng-model = "password" placeholder="Password" required=""/>
    </br>
  <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" ng-click="login()">Login</button>   
</form>
```

Answer (score 7):

This may not be specific to your problem, but I was also getting this error and it took a bit to figure out why.

I had named both a function and a variable the same, with the variable assigned in the function, and so the assignment of the variable was overriding the function and it was exploding on a second run.

You'll notice in the example the uploadFile() function as an upload.uploadFile = true; This was a wonderful file that was meant to be upload.uploadingFile - a flag used to control the behavior of a spinner. Once that was fixed, the issue went away.

Example:

```
(function()
{
  'use strict';

  angular.module('aumApp.file-upload')
  .controller('FileUploadCtrl', FileUploadCtrl);

  function FileUploadCtrl($scope, $http)
  {
    upload.uploadFile = function()
    {
      upload.uploadFile = true;
      var backendUrl = '/ua_aumcore/events/api/v1/events/uploadFile';
      var fd = new FormData();
      fd.append('file', upload.src);
      $http({ url: backendUrl, data: fd, method: 'POST', transformRequest : angular.identity, headers: { 'Content-Type' : undefined } })
      .then(function uploadSuccess(response)
      {
        upload.data = response.data;
        upload.message = "Uploaded Succesfully.";
        upload.uploadSuccess = true;
        upload.uploadingFile = false;
      },
      function uploadFailure(response)
      {
        upload.message = "Upload Failed.";
        upload.uploadSuccess = false;
        upload.uploadingFile = false;
      });
    };
  }
  FileUploadCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$http'];
})();
```

Answer (score 5):

To be callable from the view, a function must be in the $scope. Add

```
$scope.login = login;
```

to the JS code of the controller.

You also need to actually use that controller. Change

```
<div class="container" style="max-width: 300px">
```

to

```
<div ng-controller="AuthCtrl" class="container" style="max-width: 300px">
```

This is all fundamental stuff. My advice would be to learn from an AngularJS tutorial before going further.

Comment: Hi JB, I have tried inserting this line of code as well without success. I have tried within the login function and outside with same result.

Answer (score 4):

Two enable two-way binding you have to assign your login function to $scope. Replace your code for function with this:

```
$scope.login=function() {
        ref.authWithPassword({
            email    : "nick.koulias@gmail.com",
            password : "Jaeger01"
        }, function (error, authData) {
            if (error) {
                console.log("Login Failed!", error);
            } else {
                console.log("Authenticated successfully with payload:", authData);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Hi Tomislav, thanks for your response. I have tried as described but still receiving the same error.

Comment: Maybe you are missing ng-controller directive in your HTML or if you are using routing you didn't declare controller for your login.html?

Comment: Change your opening div like this:  <div class="container" style="max-width: 300px" ng-controller="AuthCtrl">

Comment: Thank you Tomislav. In the end, it was the controller declaration on the HTML file that was causing the issue. I have also wrapped the login code within a function as suggested. Worked perfectly!

Answer (score 4):

It may be a late answer by me.
But It working for me

Check form name you set 
**e.g.  ng-form="login"**

and function name
**e.g. ng-click="login()"**

Then it will not work . You have to change one of them. 
**e.g. ng-form="loginForm"**

Answer (score 0):

Explanation:

AngularJS 1.x registers any `form` DOM element that has a `name` property in `$scope` via `formDirectiveFactory`. This directive automatically instantiates  `form.FormController` if the above is true:

> If the `name` attribute is specified, the form controller is published onto the current scope under

from: angular.js:24855

Hence if you have a `<form name=myForm>` it will override your `$scope.myForm = function() { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error message. In my case, I had accidentally added a variable to the controller with the same name as a function. When that happens, you will also get this error.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).