# Angular.js "typeError: V2.example is not a function" error

Tags: html, angularjs

i am new in angular.js and i am following a tutorial that was made about a year ago 
i am trying to create a search function that takes the input and search for it in 
Github.com 
The HTML code is :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="github">

<head>
    <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="main">
    <h1>{{message}}</h1>
    <p> {{username}} </p>
    <form name="search">
        <input type="search" placeholder="enter name" ng-model="username">
        <button type="submit" ng-click="search(username)">search</button>
    </form>
    <div>
        <h1> {{user.login}} </h1>
        <img src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/{{user.gravatar_id}}">
        <p> {{user.type}} </p>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

and the JS code :

```
// Code goes here
(function () {
    var app = angular.module("github", []);
    var main = function ($scope, $http) {
        var onComplete = function (response) {
            $scope.user = response.data;
        };
        var onError = function (reasone) {
            $scope.error = "no can";
        };
        $scope.search = function (username) {
            $http.get("http://api.github.com/users/" +username).then(onComplete, onError);
        };
        $scope.message = "Git hub viewer";
    };
    app.controller("main", ["$scope", "$http", main]);
}());
```

this gives me an error >>> TypeError: v2.search is not a function <<<
for help:
i got a problem like that and the solution was not to use "main" function in global type but "search" is not global i guess .. hope this help

> here is the codepen link:

http://codepen.io/ToBeM12/pen/vGvwzo

Comment: have you tried to console

Comment: this error is on console

Comment: replace $scope with this in search function as this.search

Comment: what's the link to the tutorial?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R-lPviKS_WM&feature=youtu.be

Comment: I had the same/similar problem, found the solution here:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/32874443/737427

Comment: I had the same/similar issue, found the solution here:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/32874443/737427

Comment: My issue was that I had some old code that was setting the variable (with the same name as the function) to a value. For example, "$scope.someVar = function(...) {};", and then "$scope.someVar = 1". Fixed by renaming scope function name to something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible solution: the IIFE is written wrong.

```
(function(){...}());
```

instead of

```
(function(){...})();
```

For now, this is the only error that I could find.

Comment: @ToBe did this help you?

Answer (score 16):

the function has the same name as another variable and is conflicting in $scope

In your case just replace `$scope.search` to `$scope.searchuser` since `$scope.search` is already defined..

Comment: indeed this is a likely to happen case

Answer (score 8):

I've seen issues where the form name is the same as a scope function or variable name.  Try renaming the form to "searchForm" to avoid the conflict with $scope.search.

Comment: yes this is what happened to me. My ng-model was called editReview and I had a function called editReview also.

Answer (score 4):

An easy solution change the `form name` your form name is interfering with the function name

[AngularJS error: TypeError: v2.login is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32003458/angularjs-error-typeerror-v2-login-is-not-a-function)

The above is a similar question which helped me solve the question.

Comment: This did it for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
angular.module('github',[])  
.controller('main', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) { 
$scope.message = "Git hub viewer";
$scope.search = function (username) {
            $http.get("http://api.github.com/users/" +username).then(function(response){
                 $scope.user = response.data;
            });
        };
}])
```

Answer (score 2):

**Dont do it**

```
$scope.example = () => {
  $scope.example = 'object';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Integrator wrote correct answer. Just want to add to access to the form from your angular controller you also need to write $scope.formName. For example:

```
$scope.search.username.$invalid = true;
```

In this way you set form element to invalid. So in your case angular confuse form with method. It is a good practice to set form name like: xxxxForm to avoid such a conflicts

Answer (score 0):

I know this has already been answered, but I also had the same error.  It ended up being that I had type="submit" on my button with an ng-click.  When I removed type="submit," the function worked fine and I no longer got the error.