# AngularJs: I have the select droplist that calls a function only once when changed. How can I make it call the function whenever it is changed?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a select drop-list options that populated countries form My database and I want on successful selection of a country/or change to call a function that retrieves regions based on the selected country by `ng-change` directive. So far so good the countries can be retrieved and populated in the select drop-list option control. **Now:** what I don't seem to understand is My directive only executes once and return the regions based on the selected option but if I repeat or change the country without refreshing the browser I get *TypeError: v2.MyregionFunction is not a function*. the MyregionFUnction references to the method I call to retrieve the regions its name is **nationalRegions**. Bellow is the code in action:

In index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="options" lang='en'>

<head>
<title>Select Countries App:</title>
<script src="appModule.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="ctlOptions">

<label>Country:</label>
<select ng-model="userDomain" ng-options="location.otherName for location in userCountries"  ng-change="nationalRegions(userDomain.idCountry)">
</select>

<label>Region:</label>
<select ng-model="regionDomain" ng-options="region.regionName for region in nationalRegions">

</body>
</html>
```

Now in appModule.js

```
var app=angular.module("options",[]);
app.factory('miscellaneous',function(){


return{

    uiRequest:function(scope,inputString,callBack){

        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url:"appBackend.php",
        data: {inputString:inputString},
        dataType: "json",
        success : function(jsonResponce){


                if(callBack && typeof (  callBack )== "function") 
                {  
                    callBack(jsonResponce);
                    scope.$apply();
                }

            },

        error:function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){

                scope.colorCode="danger";
                scope.Error="Sorry, there seems to be some problem in your request. Please crosscheck provided informations.";
                scope.$apply();

            }
        })
    },


    fetchCountries:function(scope){

        var inputs={Controller:"service",Action:"userCountries"};
        var inputString = JSON.stringify(inputs);

        this.uiRootRequest(scope,inputString,function(responced){

            scope.userCountries= responced;
            scope.userDomain=scope.userCountries[0]

        });

        return scope.userDomain;
    },


    fetchRegions:function(scope,idCountry){

        var inputs={idCountry:idCountry,Controller:"service",Action:"nationalRegions"};
        var inputString = JSON.stringify(inputs);

        this.uiRootRequest(scope,inputString,function(responced){

            scope.nationalRegions= responced;
            scope.regionDomain=scope.nationalRegions[0];
        });

        return scope.regionDomain;
    }


}

});
```

And finally app.js

```
app.controller('ctlOptions',['$scope','miscellaneous',function ctlOptions($scope,miscellaneous){

$scope.userCountries=miscellaneous.fetchCountries($scope);

$scope.nationalRegions=function(idCountry){

        miscellaneous.fetchRegions($scope,idCountry);
    }

}]);
```

That is it can I get assistance where I am making a mistake please because as I said the codes function normally only once and problems arise when I re-select another country and sorry I have not included the **appBackend.php** file as to it there is no problems I hope it wont affect the debuging and if there seems to be something wrong please let Me know as its My first post here I may have many typo of the code but as it is on My local machine its perfect written without counting the problem in hand.

Comment: Can you add a working snippet of your problem. It would give much clear idea.

Comment: @Prateek Gupta thanks for your response, do you mean like a fiddle?...

Comment: Yes exactly fiddle will help better.

Comment: @Prateek Gupta I tried to prepare the plunk for this demo [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/je2OkvkGYt8tGJdXH4YF?p=preview) I cant seem to run it there but its working locally so if you take the files on your local machine you will understand the concept of the error I get in console.

Answer (score 0):

**there is a solution that was even hard to trace** in my code because it was perfect I'd say :) with a little exception that angularjs wont tell you either.
Its [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32874443/8047728) answered by **Aaron Gray**